# how can I use a shell script to replace the name of a file with that file's contents

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, sed

Say I have a file which includes an arbitrary number of other filenames (in recognizable delimiters), eg

```
original-file-contents-which-should-remain
{{filename.txt}}
more-untouchable-contents
{{dir/myfile.md}}
```

How can I use a shell script to replace the filenames (and delimiters), that is, `{{filename.txt}}` and `{{dir/myfile.md}}` with the contents of the respective files?

I've tried using sed, and while it works if I hardcode the target file name, it cannot capture the file name from the regex -- ie, the following removes `{{myfile}}` but does not enter the contents of `./myfile` (I guess maybe regex capture only works with `s/old/new` commands):

```
sed -e "/{{\(.*\)}}/ { r \1" -e "d}" somefile
```

Comment: No, that's not possible with `sed`. You have to write such a tool yourself. I believe it's doable in GNU `awk`.

Comment: Can the files you include also contain such statements so that the expansion of file names to their contents needs to be done recursively? Can those placeholder strings appear mid-line and so the included file contents also have to start/stop mid-line?

Comment: @KamilCuk `sed` is not a requirement, just what I had already tried.
@EdMorton recursion is not necessary; placeholder strings may be indented but the replacement should keep its original whitespace (ie, not preserve the indentation of the placeholder)

Comment: @dave I have updated my answer for the indentation of placeholders (even if I guess that you had already adjusted it yourself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have GNU sed, then you can use the [`e` flag for the `s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-GNU-extensions_002c-subprocesses) like this :

```
sed -f - input_file <<'EOS'
    s/^\s*{{\([^']*\)}}\s*$/cat '\1'/e
EOS
```

The pattern containing the filename is first replaced with the shell command `cat filename`, then the command is run and its output piped back into the pattern space.

As you can see, the sed program is loaded from a literal here-doc instead of the usual single-quoted string because it lets use single-quotes to enclose the filename in the shell command while keeping the whole sed command clean (and unless you fully trust the content of your input files, single-quotes are safer than double quotes). For safety again, the address regex prevent single-quotes in the filename and use both begin/end of line anchors to ensure that the shell command is not polluted by possible leading/trailing parts.

As pointed out by KamilCuk, you can use GNU awk as well. It comes with a library of additional functions, such as `readfile`, which is nice here to avoid the shell command.

```
gawk -i readfile '
    ! match($0, /^\s*\{\{(.*)}}\s*$/, refs) { print ; next }
    { printf "%s", readfile(refs[1]) }
' input_file
```

(updated for possible spaces around the patterns and unneeded escaping thanks to the [portable answer from Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61332876/how-can-i-use-a-shell-script-to-replace-the-name-of-a-file-with-that-files-cont/61343345#61343345))

Comment: Very nice. Adding `2>\/dev\/null` to the `cat` command can also handle non-existent files, if such handling is desired.

Comment: @mathguy The `e` command is interesting but I prefer when its input is strictly under control ^^ When it can potentially be fed with anything like here, it's a bit tricky...

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/^{{\(.*\)}}$/cat \1/e' file`?

Comment: @potong Well it would work indeed with the input example, but in case of filenames containing special characters (intentionally or not) such as spaces, `$`, escape sequences... at best it would just fail to import the file, at worst it may run harmful shell commands. You'd probably not want to apply this sed command to a pattern like `{{$(rm -rf myprecious)}}`, would you ? ^^

Answer (score 2):

This will work with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box given input like in your example:

```
awk '
match($0,/\{\{.*}}/) {
    fname = substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-4)
    while ( (getline < fname) > 0 ) {
        print
    }
    close(fname)
    next
}
{ print }
' file
```

e.g.

```
$ cat tam
When chapman billies leave the street,
And drouthy neebors neebors meet,
As market-days are wearing late,
{{foo}}
We think na on the lang Scots miles,
The mosses, waters, slaps, and stiles,
{{bar}}
Gathering her brows like gathering storm,
Nursing her wrath to keep it warm.

$ cat foo
And folk begin to tak the gate;
While we sit bousin, at the nappy,
And gettin fou and unco happy,

$ cat bar
That lie between us and our hame,
Whare sits our sulky, sullen dame,
```

.

```
awk '
match($0,/\{\{.*}}/) {
    fname = substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-4)
    while ( (getline < fname) > 0 ) {
        print
    }
    close(fname)
    next
}
{ print }
' tam
When chapman billies leave the street,
And drouthy neebors neebors meet,
As market-days are wearing late,
And folk begin to tak the gate;
While we sit bousin, at the nappy,
And gettin fou and unco happy,
We think na on the lang Scots miles,
The mosses, waters, slaps, and stiles,
That lie between us and our hame,
Whare sits our sulky, sullen dame,
Gathering her brows like gathering storm,
Nursing her wrath to keep it warm.
```

Sample input courtesy of [Rabbie Burns](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43815/tam-o-shanter).

Comment: I like this solution because it's portable, but I had a hard time getting it to forgive indentation whitespace in front of the delimiters

Comment: That's trivially handled by using `match()` but you don't have any leading/trailing whitespace in your example so (along with various other things that MIGHT have been present) I didn't know it had to be handled nor did your example show if the replacement text from the files should be indented to match that placeholder or not. It's extremely important when you post an example to make sure it covers all of your use cases. Anyway, I updated my answer to do what I now think you want.

Comment: Nice portable anwser. The `match()` call in mine was indeed not necessary with a pattern anchored on both sides without spaces. Checking the [POSIX ERE spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), I see that the closing brace is indeed not a special character, good to know. However in my reading of § 9.4.3 the unescaped opening braces here seem to have an unspecified result instead of just not being special, or I am missing something ? What do you think ?

Comment: @luciole75w good point, `}` is an RE interval termination char when used in the context of an RE interval (i.e. when preceded by a `{`) and `{` is an RE interval opening char unless it's the first char in a regexp (in which case it's meaning is undefined) so the 2nd `{` in `{{` could be interpreted by awk as that metachar and the meaning of the 1st is undefined. I fixed that now by just escaping both of the `{`s, thanks.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the update and ensuing discussion. Yes I guess my example could have been better. I didn't think whitespace outside of the delimiters would be an issue until seeing your solution and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using `vim`'s version of `ex`:

```
ex -c 'g/{{/s/{{\([^}]*\)}}/\=readfile(submatch(1))/g' -c 'x!' input.txt
```